# Blues and “big-legged women”

Tags: meaning, blues, etymology, euphemisms

Several blues and rock songs refer to “big-legged” women, like Led Zeppelin’s “Black Dog”:

> I don’t know, but I’ve been told
>   A big-legged woman ain’t got no soul

and Albert King’s “Born Under a Bad Sign”:

> You know wine and women is all I crave
>   A big-legged woman gonna carry me to my grave

According to a [discussion on the Straight Dope forum](http://boards.straightdope.com/sdmb/showthread.php?t=91244), this bit of imagery dates at least to the 1930s or ’40s, but the exact origin and meaning are unclear.

**Does “big-legged” have a specific connotation or euphemistic meaning?** Blues songs often use it to mean an attractive but no-good woman – but then, blues songs often refer to *all* women as attractive but no good, so that could be a coincidence. Does the term have a specific origin?

Comment: Johnnie "Geechie" Temple wrote Big Legged Woman as to Jerry Lee and muddy waters versions. Johnnie also did Lovin' Woman, Stick Up Woman, and Bow Legged Woman. To name a few. Active in the forties mostly.

Answer (score 13):

"Big-legged" was the original celebratory code phrase for the female backside.  Obviously, if you had big legs then they must culminate in an upper thigh/backside of similar proportions.  The term "Big-Legged" was used in many songs, from Jerry Lee Lewis to Albert King.  Eventually it just became the style to use the more obvious/crass description, which segued from Fat Bottom Girls to Baby Got Back to All About The Bass.  It's all the same idea, just morphing through Rock/Blues history.

Comment: That sounds reasonable. Do you have any references for it?

Answer (score 1):

Possibly the most in-depth lyrical elaboration on this theme belongs to the artist Taj Mahal (born Henry C. F. Fredericks) and his song "Big Legged Mommas Are Back In Style". [The lyrics](http://genius.com/Taj-mahal-big-legged-mommas-are-back-in-style-lyrics) are somewhat veering on NSFW.

https://youtu.be/sXfWuYaSY7g